# kinect failed openni_launch

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm using ubuntu 11.04 and ros electric.
I'm trying to use my kinect to "play" with rviz with it, but when I run "`roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`", I have a lot of errors:

```
[ERROR] [1338444270.129531457]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/depth/metric_rect] of type [depth_image_proc/convert_metric]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444270.129984353]: Service call failed!
[camera/depth/metric_rect-8] process has died [pid 13516, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-depth-metric_rect-8*.log
[ERROR] [1338444270.508399698]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/depth/metric] of type [depth_image_proc/convert_metric]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444270.508836324]: Service call failed!
[camera/depth/metric-9] process has died [pid 13525, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-depth-metric-9*.log
[ERROR] [1338444271.056389706]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/depth/points] of type [depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444271.056824167]: Service call failed!
[camera/depth/points-10] process has died [pid 13532, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-depth-points-10*.log
[ERROR] [1338444272.950893886]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/driver] of type [openni_camera/driver]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/lib/libopenni_nodelet.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444272.953776888]: Service call failed!
[ERROR] [1338444273.133584291]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/register_depth_rgb] of type [depth_image_proc/register]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444273.137115493]: Service call failed!
[camera/driver-2] process has died [pid 13487, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-driver-2*.log
[ERROR] [1338444273.468703498]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/depth_registered/metric_rect] of type [depth_image_proc/convert_metric]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[camera/register_depth_rgb-11] process has died [pid 13539, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-register_depth_rgb-11*.log
[FATAL] [1338444273.473603163]: Service call failed!
[ERROR] [1338444273.642909828]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb] of type [depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444273.646029612]: Service call failed!
[camera/depth_registered/metric_rect-13] process has died [pid 13550, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-depth_registered-metric_rect-13*.log
[ERROR] [1338444273.819169199]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/depth_registered/metric] of type [depth_image_proc/convert_metric]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444273.819648350]: Service call failed!
[camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-15] process has died [pid 13556, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb-15*.log
[ERROR] [1338444273.988537941]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/disparity_depth] of type [depth_image_proc/disparity]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444273.993103764]: Service call failed!
[camera/depth_registered/metric-14] process has died [pid 13554, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-depth_registered-metric-14*.log
[ERROR] [1338444274.165960486]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/disparity_depth_registered] of type [depth_image_proc/disparity]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1338444274.173001454]: Service call failed!
[camera/disparity_depth-16] process has died [pid 13562, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-disparity_depth-16*.log
[camera/disparity_depth_registered-17] process has died [pid 13565, exit code 255].
log files: /home/ken/.ros/log/6cbc0d00-aae6-11e1-a5f0-001422ad9fc2/camera-disparity_depth_registered-17*.log
```

I have run rostopic and I can see some /camera/depth or camera/rgb topics so I tried to see something in running `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image` but the window is empty.
I have run rviz and added a "image" and chosen the topic /camera/rgb/image_color but it says me "No image received".

I may do something wrong, I have started to read ros tuto 2 weeks ago.

Hope I'm saying anything crazy.

Cheers

Brioche

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35300/kinect-failed-openni_launch/) by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marco.puni](https://answers.ros.org/users/2474/marco.puni/) on 2012-05-30**:
I had the same errors yesterday and now I fixed. I'm not a master, and I use fuerte and ubuntu 12.04 so I don't know  if it works also for you, but I noticed that for me works only kinect for xbox, kinect for pc tell me no devices connected.

**Comment by [marco.puni](https://answers.ros.org/users/2474/marco.puni/) on 2012-05-30**:
then in my case I also see, don't know why, that works just once, then I have same errors more or less, and i have to restart ubuntu and works again.. try this, if not, somebody more expert than me maybe can help..

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-06-03**:
I have just upgraded my ubuntu and now it works fine ( rviz is lagging but it works!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Try openni_camera

```
roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

It works for me.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0